# Geometric interpretation of orbital angular momentum eigenvalues

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, angular-momentum, lie-algebra, spherical-harmonics

The eigenvalues of the square of the orbital angular momentum are defined as:

$$ \hat{L}^2  |  \phi \rangle = \hbar^2 l(l+1) |  \phi \rangle $$
$$ \hat{L}_z  |  \phi \rangle = \hbar m |  \phi \rangle, \,\, \text{where}\,\,  m = -l, -l+1, ..., l$$

This derivation typically (for example in Griffiths) goes based on the corresponding operator form of $\hat{\vec{L}}$. On the other hand when explaining the concept of how does orbital angular momentum behave in QM a certain geometrical intuition based on the following diagrams that treat $\hat{\vec{L}}$ as a vector, is helpful (at least for me). Here is the example with $l = 2$:

[image]

My question is whether there is a simple geometrically based argument that connects such a diagram (including a corresponding uncertainty relation for components of $\hat{\vec{L}}$), and the showed above eigenvalues for $ \hat{\vec{L}}^2$  or is it only "spin can be viewed as rotating electron" type of analogy?

**EDIT:** After response of Johny, I want to reformulate the question.
The radius of the cone base can be derived as: $$ R^2_{cone} = \hbar^2 (l(l+1) - m^2 )$$
How to derive the same R using commutators or uncertainty relations of the components of $\vec{L}$?

Answer (score 2):

That diagrams (if I am not mistaken) represent the possible directions of the total angular momentum.

The angle between two vectors is given by (in this case the angular momentum $\vec{L}$ and its component in the $z$-direction):
$$\theta =\cos^{-1}\left(\dfrac{\left\langle j,m\left|\vec{L}\cdot\left(0,0,L_{z}\right)\right|j,m\right\rangle }{\sqrt{\left\langle j,m\left|\vec{L}\cdot\vec{L}\right|j,m\right\rangle }\sqrt{\left\langle j,m\left|L_{z}^{2}\right|j,m\right\rangle }}\right)
 =\cos^{-1}\left(\dfrac{\left\langle j,m\left|L_{z}^{2}\right|j,m\right\rangle }{\sqrt{j\left(j+1\right)}\sqrt{m^{2}}}\right)
 \\= \cos^{-1}\left(\dfrac{m}{\sqrt{j\left(j+1\right)}}\right)$$

If you replace $m$ and $j$ by the values you obtain the following angles:
$$(j=2,m=2) =\cos^{-1}\left(\sqrt{\dfrac{2}{3}}\right)\quad
(j=2,m=1) =\cos^{-1}\left(\sqrt{\dfrac{1}{6}}\right)\quad
(j=2,m=0) =0$$

These are the angles that the total angular momentum of the states $|j,m\rangle$ makes with the $z$-axis. The set of points that makes a fixed angle with the $z$-axis is given by the surface of a cone, like the ones represented in your picture.

The interpretation is that, even when you are in the state of maximum angular momentum in the $z$-direction, there is a projection into $x$ and the $y$ direction, which comes from the non-commutativity (uncertainty) of the angular momentum operators in each direction. Hence, the interpretation of the blue surfaces is the possible total angular momentum that you can have when you are in the state $|j,m\rangle$.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. What I actually wanted to know is whether by assuming that the magnitude of $L_z$ is quantized as $m \hbar$ we can get the $l(l+1)$ relation ($j(j+1)$ in your case) from geometrical arguments? You seem to use it explicitly in formula for defining $\theta$

Comment: My point is that this geometric construction is made starting from that. How would you build this without referring to how $L^2$ acts on a given state? That would only be possible if you had an alternative way to builds this diagram (I am not aware of any). Are you asking something like: If I had experimentally measured the total angular momentum if these states and found that it lies on those surfaces, would I be able to find the properties of $L^2$?

Comment: Moreover, I do not think the quantization of $Lz$ is enough, you also need the non-commutativity of the components of the angular momentum(quantization gives you the different levels but is the uncertainty that makes the angles different from zero). However, if you have that, you can make the standard derivation of the eigenvalues of $L^2$ using the ladder operators.

Comment: What do you mean by geometrical arguments?

Comment: I think question comes down to, can we reproduce the cones, knowing only the uncertainty relations for the components and quatization of $L_z = m\hbar$. Or maybe can we find $\vec{L}$ knowing quatized  $L_z$ and uncertainty relation?

Comment: Check the section angular momentu in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ladder_operator

Comment: Check the section angular momentum (in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ladder_operator). As $L^2 = L_{_} L_{+} +L_{z}^{2}$, you can know how $L^2$ acts on those states. These require only the quantization and commutation relations. From my point of view, the uncertainty principle is a consequence of the commutation relations. You seem to want to do it the other way around: "If have uncertainty in the measurements can I derive the commutators?" (This would be enough to answer your question) or "If I have uncertainty in the measures can I know the possible values of $\vec{L}$?".

Comment: Moreover, it is impossible to find $\vec{L}$. You can never know the components of $\vec{L}$, since you can not simultaneously measure all its components. That is why you have cones instead of a line in the picture.

Comment: Maybe I will try to formulate differently. The cones come from the uncertainty in the $L_x$ and $L_y$ when I have certaing value of $L_z$. These uncertanties (their product) can be calculated using respective commutators. If I can connect the base area of the cone to the uncertainty relation (or to commutators), then by pythagorean theorem I could find $|\vec{L}|^2$ = $L^2_z + R^2_{conebase}$ (Not the actual $\vec{L}$). Now knowing that $L_z = m\hbar$, can I get the  $ |\vec{L}| = \hbar \sqrt{j(j+1)}$?

Comment: You could do that, but then you would be just defining $j$ as the value such that $\hbar ^2 j(j+1) = \hbar ^2 m^2 + R^2$ (in the assumption that QM was not discovered yet).